# Calling free with a pointer cast to one for a different type?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, casting, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

If I free a pointer that was cast from one for a **different type**, I assume it will cause a memory leak; however, I couldn't find a definitive answer.

Example:

```c
typedef struct ExampleStruct_s
{
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint32_t c;
} ExampleStruct_t;

void main(void)
{
    ExampleStruct_t *p_struct = (ExampleStruct_t*)malloc(sizeof(ExampleStruct_t));
    uint32_t *p_uint32 = (uint32_t*) p_struct;
    free(p_uint32);
}
```

Comment: As long as `free` sees the same `void *` pointer value that was returned by `malloc` then it doesn't care what pointer conversions have happened inbetween. It will free whatever block was allocated.

Comment: @IanAbbott Where can I find documentation regarding this.

Comment: @MatanLevy See the [documentation of `free()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3p.html). The only requirement is that the pointer was returned by a previous call to `malloc` or other memory allocations functions.

Comment: A pointer is just a 32/64 bit number depending on your platform. As long as you pass the same pointer to free than the one that was returned by malloc it's OK.

Comment: Let's look at it from another angle: How would you be able to free anything else than the size you got with `malloc`? `free` does not get any length indicator and does not know the type of the pointer. You can't create a leak even if you try.

Comment: @Gerhardh: That other angle would not answer the question for OP as the question shows they thought `free` may receive type information, in that receiving a pointer of one type or another would cause different behavior. This is not inconceivable, as it effectively occurs in C++ with templated functions and overload resolution. They need the information that `free` receives only the value of the pointer passed to it.

Answer (score 4):

Per C 2018 7.22.3.4, `malloc` returns a `void *`. Per 7.22.3.3, the parameter to `free` is a `void *`, and an argument to it is converted to `void *`, per 6.5.2.2 7. So the parameter to `free` is never a different type than the original pointer to the allocated space; it starts and ends as `void *`.

There would only be a problem if the value were different. The rules for pointer conversions are in 6.3.2.3. Effectively, they allow conversions through pointers to different object types as long as the pointer is correctly aligned for the referenced type. Per 7.22.3 1, the value returned by `malloc` is suitable for any *fundamental* alignment, which includes all the basic, enumerated, and pointer types and all pointers to arrays, structures, or unions whose elements or members have fundamental alignment requirements and all complete object types defined for the standard library. So, as long as you do not convert a pointer from `malloc` to some implementation-defined extended type with a greater-than-fundamental alignment requirement or to a type that uses `_Alignas` to specify a greater alignment, the conversions will effectively preserve the original value of the pointer returned from `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

The value returned from a call to [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) is a `void*` pointer (which is a pointer to an *unspecified* type) - as is the argument passed in a call to [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free). (See also: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073))

So, as long as you have not actually changed the *value* of the pointer (i.e. the address it contains), then there will be no issue with memory leaks in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The main concern here is the cast from `ExampleStruct_t *` to `uint32_t *`.  [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) will happen if the pointer is not correctly aligned.  However since the pointer value was returned from `malloc` it is properly aligned for any type, so that should be fine.

Given that, the conversion in the second line of `main` is safe.  So passing that pointer to `free` (which was returned from `malloc`) will properly free the memory.

Relevant quotes from the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

6.3.2.3p1:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> object type.  A pointer to any object  type  may  be  converted  to  a
> pointer  to `void` and  back  again;  the  result  shall compare equal
> to the original pointer

6.3.2.3p7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
> different object type.  If the resulting  pointer  is  not  correctly
> aligned for  the  referenced  type,  the  behavior  is undefined.
> Otherwise, when  converted  back  again,  the  result  shall  compare
> equal  to  the original pointer.  When a pointer to an object is
> converted to a pointer to a character type,the result points to the
> lowest addressed byte of the object.  Successive increments of the
> result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining
> bytes of the object.

7.22.3p1:

> ... The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably
> aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object
> with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such
> an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until
> the space is explicitly deallocated) ...

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
int main(void)
{
    ExampleStruct_t *p_struct = (ExampleStruct_t*)malloc(sizeof(ExampleStruct_t));
    uint32_t *p_uint32 = (uint32_t*) p_struct;
    free(p_uint32);
}
```

Is perfectly valid as the pointer returned by [malloc()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) is of type `void *` thus preserving proper alignment. (Even after a cast to a pointer of different type.)  Additionally, because the address of `p_uint32` will be precisely the same as the address of `p_struct`, no memory leak will occur upon the call to `free()`.

The only suggestions are to [remove the cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/645128) and to [use `sizeof` the object being allocated, not its type](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/201104/143513).:

```
    ExampleStruct_t *p_struct = malloc(sizeof(*p_struct));
```

...and use `int main(void){...` rather than `void main(void)`. (The standards do provide wiggle room here, but it is clearly more widely accepted as proper.)

Comment: Also change this :`void main(void)`  -> `int main(void)`

Comment: @chqrlie - edited.  I have been seeing more and more usage of the former.  I wonder what where it is all coming from?